# Is there any value of epsilon for which this limit has a finite value?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the limit:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\ln(x)}{x^{1+\epsilon}}$$
for $\epsilon>0$.

Is there any value of $\epsilon$ for which this limit is a nonzero, finite value?

I am considering the sum of $\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$ and it doesn't make sense to me how that doesn't converge. Is $x\ln(x)$ smaller than any convergent $p$-series?

Comment: well $\frac{xln(x)}{x^{1+\varepsilon}} =\frac{1}{x^\varepsilon}ln(x)$ so no. It is actually always $0$ and finite.

Comment: Your intuition is good (i.e., for the sum to converge the terms needs to go to zero faster than $1/x$, and “almost” vice versa), but this is one of those boundary cases where the summand goes to zero slightly faster than $1/x$ but the sum still diverges. In particular, for any $\epsilon >0$, your limit is zero, but for $\epsilon =0$ it is infinite. A full discussion of this particular series and a generalization is given on the Wikipedia page for the integral test for convergence.

Comment: @user8128 Could you say that there is a definitive largest function whose reciprocal sum still diverges?

Comment: @Reneo No, I don’t think so. You will always run into borderline cases like this. Again, from the Wikipedia page for the Integral Test for convergence, they give an example of a sequence of functions, each larger than the previous one, and each of which has a reciprocal sum diverging. So you always get a function “a little bit” larger whose reciprocal sum still diverges. I’m fairly certain you could mimic/adapt that example for any divergent reciprocal sum.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^\epsilon} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{-1}}{\epsilon x^{\epsilon -1}} = \frac1{\epsilon}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac1{x^{\epsilon}} = 0
\end{align}

Hence, nope, it is always $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that doesn't use L'Hôpital. If we make the substitution $u=\log x$, we find that
$$
\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^\varepsilon}=\lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{u}{e^{u\varepsilon}}=\frac{1}{\left(\lim\limits_{u \to\infty}\dfrac{e^{u\varepsilon}}{u}\right)}=0 \, .
$$